# socket.io/socket.io.js file and folder missing in chat app

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, sockets, socket.io-1.0

I'm developing a chat app based on Node.js and Express. When I run "node server" or "node server.js", it connects to my localhost:3001, but the code is missing **socket.io/socket.io.js** file, although I installed the npm package of **npm install socket.io**. Searching for this file in the default location doesn't lead to any file, while it may be the file located at **node_modules/socket.io-client/dist/socket.io.js** - though I'm not sure it has the relevant script.

After running "node server" in my **CMD or VS code Terminal**, it runs fine at **localhost:3001**. I get this result:

```
The development server is running at port 3001
User has connected!
```

That is OK, but still the file is missing and it may be important later, so that's what I'm looking to add or find inside my existing code.

My **server.js** file is the following:

```
var express = require('express');
var http = require('http');

var app = express();
var server = http.Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);

server.listen(3001, function() {
    console.log('The development server is running at port 3001');
});

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
})

io.on('connection', function (socket) {
    console.log('User has connected!');
});
```

My **index.html** file is the following:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Home</title>
        <!--<script type="text/javascript" src="socket.io/socket.io.js"></script> // Relevant file is NOT found in that path! // --> 
        <script type="text/javascript" src="node_modules/socket.io-client/dist/socket.io.js"></script> <!-- May not be the right socket.io.js file! -->
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Testting</h1>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var socket = io();
        </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

How can I add or install the socket.io.js **file** in the right path, after I already installed the socket.io package? Is there a difference solution for this problem?

Comment: The error means the port is not free, is there any process running on that port?

Comment: There is no process on the port. even if I change to a different port in my code & browser it shows the same errors. In any case, the `socket.os/socket.io.js` file is missing or located in another path that I don't know.

Comment: so, for me your code just runs fine, also I can see `Testting` in the browser.

Comment: I see it also, that part is fine. but I'm should see also, after `The development server is running at port 3001` (or a different port), the next line should be `User has connected!`. It is missing.

Comment: Okay, so can you update your question to remove the error above, It is kind of miss leading. You can edit your question to just target the problem you are facing.

Comment: OK, edited. Checked again and it stile won't show the bottom line, probably because I'm missing the right socket.io.js file.

Comment: You are src in script tag is wrong. Use this `<script type="text/javascript" src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>`

Comment: Nope. It is not the location, and it still does the same: running ok in the browser + running my port on the terminal or cmd, but doesn't run below `User has connected!`, as it should. The file of "socket.io.js" isn't located there, or wasn't created anyware. What to do now?

Comment: So how are you accessing the index.html is your browser?

Comment: I run the localhost - and it's ok. But I'm still missing the socket.io.js file of the script in the index file. Now it still fine, but I'm afraid it will cause problems in the futar developing steps. Can I fix it, add it or skip for now?

Comment: What is `var io = require('socket.io')(server);`? Did you mean: `var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);`? .... As a side note, I didn't se the `http` line written like that previously, we use `app.listen(port)`.

Comment: i Didn't understand what do you mean. anyway, I installed the socket.io package v2.3.0, but I'm still missing the file " socket.io/socket.io.js" that's required by the script in index.js.
So how can I add that FILE after I already installed the package? Or is the file in the path "node_modules/socket.io-client/dist/socket.io.js" enugh?